# Nhibernate criteria sort by child collection property

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Can anyone help me how to execute the below nhibernate criteria so that the Process class is sorted by SourceSystem.Name.

```
public abstract class Process : DomainObject<int>
{
    public virtual IList<Paramater> Parameters  { get; set; }   
}

public class Paramater : DomainObject<int>
{
    public virtual SourceSystem SourceSystem     { get; set; }  
}

public class SourceSystem : DomainObject<int>
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

process  = _session
.CreateCriteria<Process>()
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", loadingProcessId))
.UniqueResult<Process>();
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried using .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Parameters.SourceSystem.Name")) but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
process  = _session.CreateCriteria<Process>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", loadingProcessId))
    .CreateCrtieria("Parameters")
    .CreateCrtieria("SourceSystem", "SourceSystem")
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("SourceSystem.Name"))
    .UniqueResult<Process>();
```